# clojure.core.async - using >! and <! within a function call

Tags: asynchronous, clojure

I would like to be able to park when calling a function from a go-block. Using `>!` and `<!` does not work as expected.

This would park appropriately.

```
(go (<! (chan)))
```

However, if we have  a function call,

```
(defn f [c] (<! c))
(go (f (chan)))
```

The `<!` is not resovled by the go block, as it is in a function. Is there any alternatives around this? The closest one I can think of is to write a macro for `f` rather than a function - is there an alternative function, instead of `<!` and `>!` that I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [known limitation](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/wiki/Go-Block-Best-Practices#unsupported-constructs-and-other-limitations-in-go-blocks) of `core.async`. `go` macro only rewrites passed s-expression, it cannot really "look" inside bodies of functions.

I'd suggest to rewrite your example as follows (in case you want to use parking puts and gets):

```
(defn f [c] (go (<! c)))
(go (<! (f (chan))))
```

Also there's always a possibility to use blocking puts and takes (`<!!`, `>!!`).

```
> (time (dotimes [n 100000] (<!! (go (<! (let [ch (chan)] (put! ch 1) ch))))))
"Elapsed time: 1432.751927 msecs"
nil

> (time (dotimes [n 100000] (<!! (go (<! (go (<! (let [ch (chan)] (put! ch 1) ch))))))))
"Elapsed time: 1828.132637 msecs"
nil
```

According to benchmarks the initial method (if it had been supported by `core.async`) should be rougly 30% faster than the suggested workaround.

Comment: I've always used the `go` construct very simply and not hit this problem but I'd still not have realised that `(go (map <! some-chan))` wouldn't work, as explained in your link.

Comment: Is there a significant performance penalization of the method suggested?